# Outer automorphisms of a holomorph

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, automorphism-group, holomorph

Let $G$ be a finite group. Although $G$ may have outer automorphisms, an easy way to "kill" them is taking the holomorph, $G\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. However, this process may a priori produce more outer automorphisms.

> Does $G\rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ have outer automorphisms?

Surely there is an example of a group $G$ such that $G\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ has outer automorphisms, but none come to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The holomorph of the symmetric group $S_3$ is isomorphic to $S_3 \times S_3$.  The automorphism of the latter interchanging the two copies of $S_3$ is outer.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see $Hol(S_3)\cong S_3\times S_3$?

Comment: It's a special case of a more general result on complete groups.  (A group is complete if it has trivial centre and every automorphism is inner.)  If $G$ is a complete group, then $H = \operatorname{Hol}(G) \sim G\times C_{H}(G)\sim G\times G$, where the centraliser $C_H(G)$ of $G$ in the holomorph is isomorphic to $G$.  In terms of elements, you can think of the centraliser as pairs of the form $(g^{-1},\gamma_g)$, where $\gamma_g$ is the inner automorphism induced by $g$. Because $G$ is complete, $\gamma$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I see, in $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$ we have $g^{-1}\gamma_g\cdot h^{-1}\gamma_h=g^{-1}gh^{-1}g^{-1}\gamma_g\gamma_h=(gh)^{-1}\gamma_{gh}$.